# Node exec ping on Windows 10 "Object expected" Microsoft JScript runtime error

Tags: node.js, cmd, exec, windows-10, ping

I cannot get ping to execute in Node JS on Windows 10.

**Run command**

```
node ping.js
```

**ping.js**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("ping -n 1 google.com");
```

The command "ping -n 1 google.com" works correctly from prompt.

Powershell is open as an administrator, have tried it with the command prompt as well.

```
// Exec works correctly
exec("mkdir newDir");
```

[image: Windwos 10 error message]

Comment: Are you double-clicking on the .js file?

Comment: As stated: Run command > node ping.js

Comment: Did you try `child_process.execFile()`?

Comment: Interesting idea. This isn't a node issue... if I create a bat file with ping google.com -n 1 in it and run, it outputs the text over and over rather than performing the ping. If I follow the bat script at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13434317 it outputs Checking connection and gets stuck. So the ping command is not working on my Windows 10 unless I type it directly into a cmd or powershell window?!?

Comment: I'm an idiot.... recursion! Don't name your ping.bat file ping.bat, as it will call that instead of the ping command! http://superuser.com/a/382661

Comment: And again, don't name your JS file ping.js, as when running on Windows with node ping.js, it then tries to recursively run the ping.js file again... This worked on MacOS fine so was unexpected here. Renaming to test.js and running with node test.js solved issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments above:

> don't name your JS file ping.js, as when running on Windows with node ping.js, it then tries to recursively run the ping.js file again

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw this up in case someone else hits the same issue I did:

I got the same error window as @mummybot. I finally figured out it was because I was calling `npm start`, but in `package.json` I had the command defined as `"start": "index.js"` instead of `"start": "node index.js"`. If you just can't figure it out, try checking the stupid little stuff!